# How to set the initial pose manually in amcl?

Tags: navigation, gmapping, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The amcl_node initial the pose by using   `initial_pose_sub_ = nh_.subscribe("initialpose", 2, &AmclNode::initialPoseReceived, this);`  I was wondering  where does this message pub ? And is there anything I should notice when I set the initial pose manually.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277623/how-to-set-the-initial-pose-manually-in-amcl?/) by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-12-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can set the inital pose by publishing to this specific Topic, e.g. from rviz.

Obviously, the inital pose you send should be approximately at the correct Position. You could play around with the covariances to have a more spread or less spread particle cloud, if this benefits your use-case.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

per https://stackoverflow.com/a/33887151/1200764  - you can also

> specify the initial pose estimate directly as [startup parameters for amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl#Parameters), see `initial_pose_x` and other similar parameters. This is appropriate for example if you can fix these parameters in your launch file before starting the node.

e.g.
`<arg name="initial_pose_x" value="-1.0"/>  <arg name="initial_pose_y" value="10.0"/>  <arg name="initial_pose_z" value="0.0"/>`

---

Originally posted by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) with karma: 56 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on 2018-03-27**:
ok,thank u